# Looking for a closed form of a polylog expression involving the golden ratio

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, closed-form, golden-ratio

Let $\phi:=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$. In the calculation of a certain integral (which has conjecturally a closed form), the following term occured: $$ x=\left(Li_3(-\dfrac1\phi)-Li_3(\phi)\right)\log(\phi)+\left( Li_4(-\dfrac1\phi)+Li_4(\phi)\right).$$ I know that $\Im(x)=\dfrac\pi3\log^3(\phi)$, which seems to indicate that indeed for $\Re(x)$ there should be some closed form too, supposedly in terms of  $\phi,\log(\phi), \pi$ (and possibly $\zeta(3)$) $-$ but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: $1/\phi  = 1-\phi$  and [$Li_2(x)+Li_2(1-x) = \zeta(2)-\ln(x) \ln (1-x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) so $Li_2(\phi)+Li_2(1/\phi) = \zeta(2)+\ln^2(\phi)$

Comment: @user1952009 yes $Li_2$ is easy, but that isn't the question...